# Needs to handle the names which has a quotation inside

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, qsqlquery

I have two queries which inserts and updates the DB-

```
insertSQL = "insert into LineManager(LINEMANAGERID,LINEMANAGERNAME,BUSINESSGROUPID,STATUS) VALUES('" + lineManager.getLineManagerID() + "','" + lineManager.getLineManagerName() + "','" + lineManager.getBusinessGroupID() + "','" + lineManager.getStatus() + "')";

updateSQL = "update LineManager set BUSINESSGROUPID ='" + lineManager.getBusinessGroupID() + "' , LINEMANAGERNAME ='" + lineManager.getLineManagerName() + "' , STATUS ='" + lineManager.getStatus() + "' where LINEMANAGERID='" + lineManager.getLineManagerID() + "'";
```

so far it was working fine for the regular names, but it is facing issues when the LineManager name is like -'Doko N'dah, Mr. Dominick'. It's throwing exceptions during execution.

Can anybody help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use parameters.  Don't munge query strings with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bind variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-sqlstatements.html):

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("insert into LineManager(LINEMANAGERID,LINEMANAGERNAME,BUSINESSGROUPID,STATUS) VALUES(:id,:name,:groupid:status)");
query.bindValue( ":id",      lineManager.getLineManagerID() );
query.bindValue( ":name",    lineManager.getLineManagerName() );
query.bindValue( ":groupid", lineManager.getBusinessGroupID() );
query.bindValue( ":status",  lineManager.getStatus() );
query.exec();
```